# Javascript tile map collision detect when player moves less than tile size

Tags: javascript

Javascript Tile map collision detect

This question my have been asked and answered many times.
If so, I could find it.

My map is a scrolling map.
The 3 is for the solid tiles.
The 'x' is for my player start position.

```
var gameMap_1 = [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
var tileW = 50, tileH = 50;
var mapW = 40, mapH = 20;
```

As you can see, my tiles are 50 x 50 pixels.
My player is also 50 x 50 pixels.

My problems comes in by not moving my player 50 pixels at a time.

The collision for that would work perfectly as I would just look
to the tile ahead of which way the player moves and stop him.

But it makes the player clunky looking to move a full block at a time, so
the player moves 10 pixels to make him look smoother moving around.

Now I'm lost trying to figure this out. I've been working at this problem for over 3 weeks now.
I could sure use some real help with this.

This is how I determine my location at all times

```
WhatArray = 800 - (parseInt(offsetX / 50) + (parseInt(offsetY / 50)) * 40 + 1);

if ((gameMap_1[WhatArray -1]) == 3) {offsetX += 10};
```

[Top image works great, Bottom is what happens when he's not in line with the 50 pixel block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVOW3.png)

```
function Engine(){

var ctx = null;
var gameMap_1 = [
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 'x', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];
var tileW = 50, tileH = 50;
var mapW = 40, mapH = 20;
var currentSecond = 0, frameCount = 0, framesLastSecond = 0;

var LocateX = 1;
var LocateY = 1;
var i = 0;

while (i < gameMap_1.length) {

i++
LocateX++;

tempX = tempX - 50;

    if (LocateX > 40) {tempX = 1950; LocateX = 1; LocateY++; tempY = (tempY - 50)}; 

    if (gameMap_1[i] == 'x') {tempXX = LocateX; tempYY = LocateY; break};

}

    if (tempXX == 0 && tempYY == 0) {tempY = 950};

var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
can.tabIndex = 1; 
ctx.font = '20px sans';

// player's position
var playerX = 500;
var playerY = 330;

// how far offset the canvas is
var offsetX = 0;
var offsetY = 0;

function draw() {

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(offsetX, offsetY);

ctx.fillStyle='Gray';
ctx.fillRect(-1900, -900, 3000, 1950);

ctx.drawImage(background, -1450, -620, 2000, 990); // Background will show up behind Blank tiles

drawGame();

function drawGame()
{

if(ctx==null) { return; }

var sec = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);

if (sec!=currentSecond)
{

currentSecond = sec;
framesLastSecond = frameCount;
frameCount = 1;

}

else { frameCount++; }

for(var yg = 0; yg < mapH; ++yg)

{

for(var xg = 0; xg < mapW; ++xg)

{

switch(gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)])

{

case 0:

}

    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 0) {ctx.drawImage(tile_back, xg*tileW-1450, yg*tileH-620, tileW, tileH)};
    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 1) {ctx.drawImage(tile_rock, xg*tileW-1450, yg*tileH-620, tileW, tileH)};
    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 2) {ctx.drawImage(tile_grass, xg*tileW-1450, yg*tileH-620, tileW, tileH)};
    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 3) {ctx.drawImage(cave, xg*tileW-1450, yg*tileH-620, tileW, tileH)};
    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 'x') {ctx.drawImage(tile_grass, xg*tileW-1450, yg*tileH-620, tileW, tileH)};
    if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 'x' && NewGame == 0) {offsetX = tempX; offsetY = tempY; NewGame = 1};
        
}}}

ctx.drawImage(SpriteSheet, Spritex, Spritey, 100, 100, playerX-offsetX, playerY-offsetY, 50, 50);  // Draw the Player

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(playerX-offsetX - 450, playerY-offsetY - 330, 1000, 50);
ctx.fillRect(playerX-offsetX - 500, playerY-offsetY - 330, 50, 700);
ctx.fillRect(playerX-offsetX + 550, playerY-offsetY - 330, 50, 700);
ctx.fillRect(playerX-offsetX - 450, playerY-offsetY + 320, 1000, 50);

WhatArray = 800 - (parseInt(offsetX / 50) + (parseInt(offsetY / 50)) * 40 + 1);

ctx.fillText("offsetX: " + offsetX + "   offsetY: " + offsetY, playerX-offsetX - 400, playerY-offsetY - 300);

ctx.fillText("playerX-offsetX : " + (playerX-offsetX) + "   playerY-offsetY: " + (playerY-offsetY), playerX-offsetX - 400, playerY-offsetY - 250);

ctx.fillText("WhatArray: " + WhatArray + " Above Number " + (WhatArray - 40) , playerX-offsetX - 400, playerY-offsetY - 220); // ((offsetY/ 50) +1 )

ctx.fillText("Tile Value: " + gameMap_1[WhatArray - 1] + "  Value Up " + gameMap_1[WhatArray - 41], playerX-offsetX - 400, playerY-offsetY - 190);

LocateUpX = (((ActualX * 50  - 1950) - 50) + 500);
LocateUpY = (((ActualY * 50  - 950) - 100) + 300);

ctx.restore();

}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (key == 37) {   //left

Spritex = 0;

    if (((gameMap_1[WhatArray -1]) == 3) || ((gameMap_1[WhatArray - 40]) == 3)) { // This is for the block to the left and above

// Collision detected!
}

    if (((gameMap_1[tempX]) !== 3) && ((gameMap_1[WhatArray -1]) !== 3)) {

offsetX += 10};

}

if (key == 39) {   //right

Spritex = 200;

    if ((gameMap_1[WhatArray]) == 3) {

// Collision detected!

offsetX += 10;

}

offsetX -= 10;

}

    if (key == 38) {   //up

Spritex = 300;

    if ((gameMap_1[WhatArray -40]) !== 3) {

// Collision detected!

offsetY += 10;

}}

    if (key == 40) {   //down

Spritex = 100;

    if ((gameMap_1[WhatArray]) !== 3) {

offsetY -= 10;

}}

     if (offsetY < 0) {offsetY = 0};
     if (offsetY > 950) {offsetY = 950};

     if (offsetX < 0) {offsetX = 0};
     if (offsetX > 1950) {offsetX = 1950};

}

function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, hours, seconds;
setInterval(function () {

hours = parseInt(timer / 3600, 10)

seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;

draw();

    if (--timer < 0) {

timer = duration;

}

}, 10);

}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = 0,  /* Minutes */
display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);

};

}
```

Comment: Since the player can only move inside these fixed boxes, you could first check a collition and if not a forloop to move the player 10px at a fixed interval until reaches the 50px, this is the easy way.  if you want some collitions you could converte your array into "boxes" use math to check if the (x,y) value are inside one box in the next move if so dont move the player.

Comment: Could you provide some minimum reproducible code?

Comment: Here's a link that may help better understand what I have.http://gllundy.com/testgame/.  I'm not a programmer by no means and my code is probably not very readable to you. I'm self taught from 5 or 6 years of pulling code apart and seeing what happens.

Comment: What actually is your question? I see some observations, but can't actually tell what you're trying to find out. Is the problem the character doesn't end up in the middle of a tile when you move by amounts smaller than a tile, or is it something else? If it is this, you could say numStepsToNextTile = tileSize / moveStepSize. You would then need to move the character numStepsToNextTile times before its in the middle of the next tile. You could use a counter to keep track of this, then simply ignore input unless the counter was 0

Comment: Set the counter to the number of steps, then move the char and decrease the counter for each step of the animation. When it's zero again, you've moved enough times to be ready to (accept a user) move again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not have explained it properly. As long as I move the player 1 tile or 50 pixels at a time everything works great as the tiles are 50 pixels. But what I would like to do if possible is to move 10 pixels at a time in any direction and still be able to get the collision detect to make it smoother and more responsive as you play.

Comment: That's what I'd wondered, and hence the suggestion to use a coordinate system that knows nothing of and doesn't care about the size of the tiles. In case it matters, what are you trying to detect collisions with? Other players, enemies, tiles? Something else perhaps? You've said what you want to happen, but not explained what _is_ happening.

Comment: I will be adding enemies along with objects to collect as well.
I have made a few other games such as this one, https://gllundy.com/munk/index.html
but haven't tried a shooter game, something similar to Biolab Disaster https://playbiolab.com
and others.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this code. The part I spoke of is implemented using window.requestAnimationFrame and the flag variable `playerAnimationPlaying`.

In the keyhandler, I simply do nothing if the flag is set. That way, we always move the player's sprite an exact number of times, and therefore, an exact number of pixels. The player will always end up in the middle of a tile and we've always got the position to collision detect against other items.

The coordinate-system stuff I'd mentioned may not be necessary for your purposes. (Though with a scrolling field and thus, a moving viewport, it may be rather handy)

Movement with arrowkeys/num-pad. The speed of movement is different, since we're using the same number of steps to move 70.71 pixels when moving diagonally, instead of 50 when moving vertically or horizontally. That just comes down to the nSteps and stepSize calc. To get constant speed, you'd make stepSize constant and vary nSteps.

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function qs(sel,parent=document){return parent.querySelector(sel)}
function qsa(sel,parent=document){return parent.querySelectorAll(sel)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    drawFrame();
    animateMove(50,0);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeypress, false);
}

let playerX=0, playerY=0;
let tileSize=50;
let playerAnimationPlaying=false;


function onKeypress(evt)
{
    // ignore keystroke if animation currently playing
    if (playerAnimationPlaying == true)
        return;
        
    switch( evt.code )
    {
        // left/right/up/down
        case "ArrowLeft":
        case "Numpad4":
            animateMove(-50,0);
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
        case "Numpad6":
            animateMove(50,0);
            break;
        case "ArrowUp":
        case "Numpad8":
            animateMove(0, -50);
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
        case "Numpad2":
            animateMove(0, 50);
            break;

        // diagonals
        case "Numpad7":
            animateMove(-50, -50);
            break;
        case "Numpad9":
            animateMove(50, -50);
            break;      
        case "Numpad1":
            animateMove(-50, 50);
            break;
        case "Numpad3":
            animateMove(50, 50);
            break;
    }
}


function animateMove(dx,dy)
{
    playerAnimationPlaying = true;
    let stepSize = 1;
    let nSteps = Math.max( Math.abs(dx/stepSize), Math.abs(dy/stepSize) );
    let stepX=dx/nSteps, stepY=dy/nSteps;
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame( animationStep );
    
    function animationStep()
    {
        playerX += stepX;
        playerY += stepY;
        drawFrame();
        nSteps--;
        if (nSteps)
            window.requestAnimationFrame( animationStep );
        else
            playerAnimationPlaying = false;
    }
}

function drawFrame()
{
    let can = qs('canvas');
    drawBkg(can);
    drawPlayer(can);
}

function drawBkg(canvas)
{
    let width=canvas.width, height=canvas.height;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    for (let y=0; y<height; y+=tileSize)
    {
        for (let x=0; x<width; x+=tileSize)
        {
            let tx=x/tileSize, ty=y/tileSize;
            if (ty&1 ^ tx&1)
                ctx.fillRect(x,y,tileSize,tileSize);
        }
    }
}

function drawPlayer( canvas )
{
    let width=canvas.width, height=canvas.height;
    let ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc( playerX+tileSize/2, playerY+tileSize/2,
             tileSize/2,
             0*Math.PI, 2*Math.PI );
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
    border: solid 4px #888;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=256 height=256></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It only took a month...lol  I created another array to get the X,Y coordinance of each tile tagged as 0 or 3 to make them solid. Then when a key is pressed it would check each array to see if the player collided with a tile. Works Great. Thanks for your help anyway.

```
if (gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 0 || gameMap_1[((yg*mapW)+xg)] == 3) {
    CollisionXYCount++;
    CollisionX[CollisionXYCount] = xg*tileW-1450;
    CollisionY[CollisionXYCount] = yg*tileH-620;
} // Solid tiles for Collision

if (key == 39) { // Right Arrow Key
    Dir = "Right";
    offsetX = offsetX - 10;
    Spritex = 203;

    var i = -1;
    while (i < CollisionX.length) {
        i++;
        if (playerX-offsetX + tileW > CollisionX[i] && 
            playerX-offsetX < CollisionX[i] && 
            playerY-offsetY + tileH > CollisionY[i] && 
            playerY-offsetY - tileH < CollisionY[i]) {
            offsetX += 10;
        }
    }
}
```